# Representation of the lie algebra of a simply connected algebraic group $G$ induces a representation of the group itself

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a simply connected algebraic group over $C$. We know that a representation of an algebraic group 
$$\phi : G \to GL(V)$$

induces a representation of its lie algebra  (taking the differential of this map $\phi$) .

Now, if $G$ is simply connected and we are given a representation 
   $$\psi : Lie(G) \to gl(W)$$

Is that true that this induces a representation of the group $G$ ? This fact comes up in a paper I am reading and I am not able to realise it.

Please help me in realising how the simple connectedness is used here to get the representation of the group itsef.

Thanks

Comment: Are you assuming that the representation of the Lie algebra is finite dimensional? Are you only assuming $G$ to be simply connected, or also semisimple?

Comment: I don't know much about algebraic groups, but this is a general fact about Lie groups: a lie algebra homomorphism can be lifted to the groups if the domain is simply connected.  You can find a proof in Lee's smooth manifolds book or Warner's book.  If you don't have access to those, I can write a proof, but again I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Timkinsella I think the proof you are referring to will be really helpful to me. I would appreciate if you could give the proof here or atleast explicitly define the representation of the group induced by the representation of its lie algebra. Thank you !

Comment: So, looking inJantzen, this certainly holds if $G$ is semisimple and the Lie algebra representation is locally finite (as a module for the enveloping algebra). But as far as I can tell, it should be more straightforward in characteristic $0$ (based on some remarks in the book).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Lol, so evidently my suggestion was pretty naive! I will steer clear of the algebraic-groups tag :)

Comment: @Timkinsella actually, it is not quite that far off I think. But obviously some weird things happen if you try to list an infinite dimensional irreducible representation.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ and $H$ be Lie groups, $G$ simply connected, and suppose a lie algebra homomorphism $\phi : \frak{g}\rightarrow \frak{h}$.  The graph of $\phi$ is a lie sub algebra of $\frak{g}\oplus \frak{h}$.  Let $L$ be the corresponding Lie subgroup in $G\times H$.  The composition $L\subset G\times H \rightarrow G$ (where the second map is projection) is a Lie group homomorphism and a local diffeomorphism at $e_L$.  It is therefore a covering map.  Since $G$ is simply connected, the map is invertible: $G\rightarrow L$.  Post-composing with the projection to $H$, we have lifted $\phi$.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could more clearly define the graph of the map $\phi$.

Comment: Oh sure. Its just $\{(g, \phi(g)):g\in \frak{g}\}$.  It's a subalgebra because $\phi $ is an algebra homomorphism

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Note that while you requested this answer in a comment, it does not actually answer the stated question, as this is about Lie groups, rather than about algebraic groups (and there are some subtle differences).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay. I'll try to move this to a comment, or what?

Comment: I think it looks fine as an answer, if accompanied by a note that this is for the analoguous situation for Lie groups.

Comment: @Timkinsella Can we say that the graph of $\phi$ is isomorphic to $Lie(G)$ as lie algebras ? If this is true, then the map you are taking about $L \to G $ is an isogeny since they have isomorphic lie algebras. But since $G$ is simply connected, this isogeny needs to be an isomorphism and hence invertible. Please let me know if this argument is true. Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Please read my above comment and let me know if what I am thinking is fine. Thanks !

Comment: @Timkinsella How do we further show that if we take the differential of the induced map we get the same map between the lie algebras which we started with. Please help. Thanks !!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft How do we further show that if we take the differential of the induced map we get the same map between the lie algebras which we started with. Please help. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer by Tim kinsella explains why it induces a Lie group representation but does not address algebraicity.

Algebraicity is false without a robustness assumption such as that $G$ is semisimple. Take for example $G = \mathbb C$ and a $1$-dimensional Lie algebra representation $G \to \mathfrak{gl}_1(\mathbb C) \cong \mathbb C$ given by $z \mapsto z$. The induced Lie group homomorphism $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C^\times$ is the exponential map, which is not rational.

Since you ask about simple connectedness, this is needed even for the Lie group statement: there is an isomorphism $\mathfrak{pgl}_n(\mathbb C) \cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$ as Lie-algebras (there is a natural map from the latter to the former and it is an isomorphism) but it does not come from a representation $\operatorname{PGL}_n(\mathbb C) \to \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$.

---

Now for a positive answer: I find the book *Lie groups and algebraic groups* by Onishchik and Vinberg helpful for Lie group vs algebraic group questions.

Assume $G$ is a complex (linear, connected) algebraic group that is semisimple and simply connected. Connected means Zariski-connected, but it is connected for the Euclidean topology either way: A connected algebraic group over any field is irreducible, and the complex points of an irreducible complex variety are connected in the Euclidean topology (https://mathoverflow.net/a/12896/50929). I identify $G$ with its complex points.

Take a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$. Simply connected refers to the Euclidean topology, so by topological considerations there is a Lie group lift $G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$. Now we conclude using the following:

**Fact.** With $G$ connected semisimple and $H$ any complex algebraic group, any Lie group homomorphism $f : G \to H$ is algebraic.

Proof: we have a Lie group homomorphism $G \to G \times H$ given by $(1, f)$. Its image, call it $G'$, is a semisimple Lie group. It is therefore automatically closed; this follows from Proposition 7.9 in Knapp, *Lie groups beyond an introduction* and also from §1.4.2, Theorem 3 in Onishchik-Vinberg. Moreover, it is automatically a closed algebraic subgroup; this follows from §3.3.3 in Onishchik-Vinberg. Now the projection $G' \to G$ is algebraic, and a bijection, and therefore the inverse is algebraic so that $f$ is algebraic. (This last part of the argument comes from §3.3.4, Theorem 4 in Onishchik-Vinberg, if you want references.) $\square$

Comment: +1, just to point out, it's not semisimplicity that matters (which is like saying that tori and unipotent groups are the issue) and more like reductivity that matters (which is like saying that unipotent groups are the issue--think about the exponential map $\mathbb{G}_a(\mathbb{C})\to \mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{C})$). In fact, your fact holds true even with just a reductive hypothesis on the source (where I assume for you a homomorphism should be holomorphic?). For example, see Proposition D.2.1 of Conrad's Luminy notes (http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf).

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks! I wrote this answer with the hope that somebody would comment with a better reference.